# Perl: How To capture WMIC output into variable

Tags: perl, wmic

I am using below code to get drivename, freespace and total space of drive.

```
my @pnames = `wmic /node:"IP" /user:"UserName" /password:"password" LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='H:'" Get DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size`;

print "@pnames";
```

Above command displays output as below:

```
DeviceID FreeSpace    Size

H:        51664236544  214753832960
```

How can I read the `DeviceID` into `$DriveName` variable, `FreeSpace` into `$FreeSpaceOnDrive` variable and `Size` into `$TotalSpace` variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternative: [DBD::WMI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::WMI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the output in a scalar variable and check it with a regular expression, something like this:

```
my ($DriveName, $FreeSpaceOnDrive, $TotalSpace);
my $pnames = `wmic /node:"IP" /user:"UserName" /password:"password" LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='H:'" Get DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size`;

if( $pnames =~ m!\s+([\w:]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)! ) {
   ($DriveName, $FreeSpaceOnDrive, $TotalSpace) = ($1, $2, $3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to use `split` to get these values out.

I'm not clear whether there's really a blank line after the header in your ouput, but if so then you need

```
my ($dev_id, $free_space, $size) = split ' ', $pnames[2];
```

If there is no blank line then just change the `split` to work on `$pnames[1]` instead.